# How to convert Gzip Stream response Okhttp3 into JSON

Tags: java, android, gzip, okhttp, gson

How to convert GZip to JSON?

My code is this:

```
private FileContentModel getDbData(String url)throws ApiException, IOException, ConnectionException {
        TypeToken<FileContentModel> typeToken = new TypeToken<FileContentModel>() {};
        return getData(url, getPostModel(), typeToken);
}



private <T> T getData(String url, PostModel postModel, TypeToken<T> typeToken) throws ApiException, IOException, ConnectionException {
        Response response = new CallApi<T>(Connection.getOfficeApiUrl(context))
                .Post(url, postModel);

        if (response.code() != 200) throw new ApiException(context, response);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        T obj = gson.fromJson(response.body().charStream(),
                typeToken.getType());
        return obj;
}

public Response Post(String route, Object object) throws IOException  {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(MIME_JSON), gson.toJson(object));

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(baseUrl + route)
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
            .build();

    return okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank from [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink)

```
private <T> T getData(String url, PostModel postModel, TypeToken<T> typeToken) throws ApiException, IOException, ConnectionException {
        Response response = new CallApi<T>(Connection.getOfficeApiUrl(context))
                .Post(url, postModel);

        if (response.code() != 200) throw new ApiException(context, response);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        GZIPInputStream gzis = new GZIPInputStream(response.body().byteStream());
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(gzis);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(reader);
        List<BranchModel> obj =   gson.fromJson(reader,
            new TypeToken<List<BranchModel>>(){}.getType());
        return obj;
}
```